# Scrape Fandango Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Trying to scrape in Node.js for the first time. The movie list on [fandango](https://www.fandango.com/movies-in-theaters) is nested in a few divs so does that mean I do something like: `$('div[id="page"]').find('div > div > div > div > ul > li').each` . And then when I log the html in console it seems different than when I inspect it on Chrome. Some of the movies are missing and the ul class names are different on the log. Is this normal?

```
 const axios = require('axios');
 const cheerio = require('cheerio');

 const url = 'https://www.fandango.com/movies-in-theaters';

 axios(url)
   .then(response => {
     const html = response.data;
     console.log(html);
     const $ = cheerio.load(html);
     const movies = $('ul.browse-movielist > li');

     const openingThisWeek = [];

     movies.each(function () {
        console.log("Found the list");   // this doesn't get called
        const title = $(this).find('.heading-style-1 browse-movielist--title poster-card--title').text();
        openingThisWeek.push({
        title,
      });
     });

     console.log(openingThisWeek);   
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fandango using the client-side rendering for the Opening Movie, so we can't use axios to fetch it.

Alternative way is using the headless-browser to crawl the data. I'm using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

(async () => {
  const url = "https://www.fandango.com/movies-in-theaters";

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const body = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.outerHTML);
  await browser.close();
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const movies = [];
  $(".browse-movielist > li").each((i, item) => {
    const $item = $(item);
    const title = $item.find(".poster-card--title").text();
    movies.push({
      title
    });
  });
  console.log(movies);
})();
```